# Why doesn't my transaction go through?

Tags: transactions, mtgox

I ask to buy for 253, price drops below, the transaction does not go through, and it goes up again.

Explanation anyone? or is this something i should ask the mt.gox staff?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

MtGox is a roach sack of bugs. People start with it for liquidity and fame, but it is the least reliable bitcoin exchange. Anything else is better.